# How would I add a button in that would change the font size without changing font?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an app that I want to change the UILabels sizes without changing the font. I have tried the :
systemFontOfSize
property but it changes the font size and the font back to the standard 'Helvetica' font.

Just to note I have UILabels that are taking multiple fonts so I don't want the:
[labelName setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Font" size: labelName.font.pointSize]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [UIFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/systemFontOfSize%3a) class reference, there is a method that is called `fontWithSize:`. The description is:

> Returns a font object that is the same as the receiver but which has
>   the specified size instead.

You can try that, or some of the other useful methods described. Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
 I got it, look at this (it is a sample project for the iPhone):

    http://drp.ly/Gl9cb
```